# vim under tmux looses color scheme in iterm2

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, tmux

```
OSX - sierra
iterm2 3.0.13
tmux 2.3
vim 8.0.176
```

colors work fine in bare iterm2:

[image]

but under tmux:

[image]

iterm2:

```
echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

tmux:

```
echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

tmux config

[image]

vimrc

[image]

I'm running out of ideas. and google foo is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t_*` is needed because these are not set automatically by vim for anything but `xterm`. But tmux only supports `screen-256`

```
:h xterm-true-color
```

Moving `t_8f` and `t_8b` below `set termguicolors` fixed my problem.

long version: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/993

Answer (score 0):

A search for 'tmux vim colors wrong' turned up [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125526/vim-in-tmux-display-wrong-colors).  Start tmux with the -2 option to force 256 colors.

Comment: It's supposed to force tmux into 256 color mode. I've got that aliased in my configuration files and don't have the terminal-overrides in my tmux configuration.